# How do I index unhidden element on top, instead of whatever is next in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

I am trying to code a card drawing emulation and I have run into a problem. After I've flipped a random card I cannot get that exact card to stay on top - instead whatever is furthest down in the DOM stays on top, and the other cards just falls below it.

I have tried with Z-index (which did nothing), and I believe this might be the answer, but I think I'm overseeing something. Also tried to hide the element with a timer, which still causes overlapping issues.

Anyone who could point me in the direction of how to make the pulled card stay on top regardless of it's placement within the DOM? I've even tried to give DOM element further up higher z-index which does nothing to the order. So I have a hard time finding the problem!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Papadan/sdj75zr3/)

Full code:

```js
// Functions for displaying the random content when card is clicked

var backgroundImage = document.getElementById("bg");

function first_function(){
console.log("test1");
document.getElementById("a").classList.remove("hide");
  document.getElementById("a2").classList.remove("hide");
document.getElementById("a").style.color = "white";
}

function second_function(){
console.log("test2");
document.getElementById("b").classList.remove("hide");
  document.getElementById("b2").classList.remove("hide");
document.getElementById("b").style.color = "white";
}

function third_function(){
console.log("test3");
document.getElementById("c").classList.remove("hide");
document.getElementById("c2").classList.remove("hide");
document.getElementById("c").style.color = "white";
}

function last_card(){
console.log("last one");
document.getElementById("last").classList.remove("hide");
document.getElementById("last2").classList.remove("hide");
document.getElementById("last").style.color = "white";
}

// Splice array 1 item at a time

Array.prototype.randsplice = function () {
var randomnbr = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length);
// Removed extra variable
return this.splice(randomnbr, 1);
};

// Use an eventlistener to wait for the DOM to load so that we can depend on DOM elements being available

window.addEventListener("load",function(){

// Setup the array we will use for this example
var my_array = [
    first_function,
    second_function,
    third_function,
];

// Attach a click event handler to our button

backgroundImage.onclick = function(){

// Hide content after each click

var list = document.getElementsByClassName("hide-all");
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
list[i].classList.add("hide");
}

// Modify my_array and display result

if(my_array.length > 0){   
var new_numb = my_array.randsplice();
new_numb[0].apply(null);

// Animation making card unclickable until animation is complete 

backgroundImage.classList.add("animstart");
backgroundImage.addEventListener( "animationend",  function() {
backgroundImage.classList.remove("animstart"); 
} );

// Check if the array is empty and if so, perhaps display a message

}else{
last_card();
backgroundImage.classList.add("no-click");
}
}
});
```

```css
body, html{
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
background-color: #333;
}
/* Background card */

.bgcard{
width:9.4vw;
display: inline-block;
position:absolute;
left:35.4%;
top:66.2%;
cursor: pointer;
}

/* Animation making card unclickable start */

.animstart{
animation-name: examples;
animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes examples {
    0%   { pointer-events: none;}
    100% { pointer-events: none;}
}

.cards{
z-index: 100;
transform: rotateY(180deg);
width: 14vw;
font-size: 1.2vw;
transition: 0.6s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
position: relative;
animation-name: flip;
animation-duration: 0.6s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes flip {
from { transform: rotateY(180deg); left: -10vw; }
to { transform: rotateY(0deg); left: 0vw; }
}

 @keyframes flips {
from { transform: rotateY(0deg); left: -10vw; }
to { transform: rotateY(180deg); left: 0vw; }
}

.frontcard {
width: 14vw;
z-index: 200;
transform: rotateY(0deg);
transition: 0.6s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
position: relative;
animation-name: flips;
animation-duration: 0.6s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-delay: 0s;
}

.frontcard, .back {
backface-visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
}

.text-wrap{
padding-left: 200px;
width: 50vw;
position: absolute;
}

p{
top: 10%;

animation-name: hidden;
animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

h2{
top: 5%;
animation-name: hidden;
animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

.pulled-card-container{
position: absolute;
right: 24%;
top:66.2%;;
display: inline-block;
z-index: 100;
perspective: 1000;
}

.pulled-card-container-done{
position: absolute;
right: 24%;
top:66.2%;;
display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes example {
    0%   { left:-10vw;}
    25%  { left:0px;}
    50%  { left:0px;}
    75%  { left:0px;}
    100% { left:0px;}
}

  @keyframes hidden {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    25%  {opacity: 0;}
    50%  {opacity: 0;}
    75%  {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.no-click{
pointer-events: none;
cursor: none;
}

.hide{
display: none; 
}

.hideanim{
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadein;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-name: fadein; 
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  @keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="all-wrap">

<!-- Containers with information -->

<div id="a" class="aa hide ">
    <div id="a2" class="text-wrap hide hide-all">
    <h2>X of Cards</h2>
    <p>First Displayed Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pulled-card-container">
        <img class="cards lol1"src="https://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/n-d57o0b/1kujmu/products/297/images/924/2D__57497.1440113502.1280.1280.png?c=2" width="200px" height="300px">
        <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1363007/1810/i/950/depositphotos_18105995-stock-photo-card-back.jpg" alt="" width="200px" height="300px" alt="" class="frontcard">
    </div> 
</div>

<div id="b" class="ab hide">
    <div id="b2" class="text-wrap hide hide-all">
    <h2>Y of Cards</h2>
    <p>Second displayed text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pulled-card-container">
        <img class="cards lol2"src="https://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/n-d57o0b/1kujmu/products/297/images/928/6D__92916.1440113530.1280.1280.png?c=2" width="200px" height="300px">
        <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1363007/1810/i/950/depositphotos_18105995-stock-photo-card-back.jpg" alt="" width="200px" height="300px" alt="" class="frontcard">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="c" class="ac hide">
    <div id="c2" class="text-wrap hide hide-all">
<h2>Z of Cards</h2>
    <p>Third displayed text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pulled-card-container">
        <img class="cards lol3"src="https://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/n-d57o0b/1kujmu/products/297/images/932/10H__11470.1440113568.1280.1280.png?c=2" width="200px" height="300px">
        <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1363007/1810/i/950/depositphotos_18105995-stock-photo-card-back.jpg" alt="" width="200px" height="300px" alt="" class="frontcard">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="last" class="hide">
    <div id="last2" class="text-wrap hide hide-all">
<h2>Last of Cards</h2>
    <p>The last card in the deck</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pulled-card-container">
        <img class="cards" src="https://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/n-d57o0b/1kujmu/products/297/images/932/10H__11470.1440113568.1280.1280.png?c=2" alt="" width="200px" height="300px">
                <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1363007/1810/i/950/depositphotos_18105995-stock-photo-card-back.jpg" alt="" width="200px" height="300px" alt="" class="frontcard">
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Background card -->
<div class="bgcard" id="bg">
    <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1363007/1810/i/950/depositphotos_18105995-stock-photo-card-back.jpg" alt="" width="200px" height="300px">
</div>

</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After fidgeting around some more I found my grave error. Here's the answer, in case anyone ever wonders:

I had z-index on pulled-card-container that conflicted. After removing that, and doing a

```
var zNumb = 300;
zNumb++;
document.getElementById("imgOne").style.zIndex = zNumb;
```

on each function it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

When using z-index, you will need to set the position to relative or absolute ... pretty sure, like 90% sure.

Comment: They do - and still I cannot get it to work. So I'm thinking I might have done something somewhere else that is interfering with it!

Comment: Are you using the scale property on these cards or the parent element? Sometimes scaled elements ignore z positioning.